# Using a condition for having attributes in a paper-input

Tags: lit-html

I'm using lit-html with a `paper-input` which is a polymer 3 element. I would like to make a condition where some attributes are put in the `paper-input`-attributes by a condition.

**Note this does not seem to be related to paper-input. Different error occurs using simple input**

```
render(){
    return html`
                                             <!--Using placeholder or value depending on a condition-->
        <paper-input label="Video title" type="text"
            id="titleInput" name="title" ${((true) ? html`placeholder="${this.videotitle}" `: html`value="${this.videotitle}" `)}>
        </paper-input>
`;}
```

I'm expecting to have either the placeholder or the value set based on the condition.

```
/*Error message from console*/
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null
    at _prepareTemplate (template.ts:102)
    at new Template (template.ts:203)
    at Object.templateFactory (shady-render.ts:94)
    at NodePart._commitTemplateResult (parts.ts:285)
    at NodePart.commit (parts.ts:230)
    at render (render.ts:57)
    at Function.render (shady-render.ts:284)
    at HTMLElement.update (lit-element.ts:231)
    at HTMLElement.performUpdate (updating-element.ts:772)
    at HTMLElement._enqueueUpdate (updating-element.ts:717)
```

When using a input field like below:

```
<input 
${((true) ? html`placeholder="${this.videotitle}" `: html`value="${this.videotitle}"`)} >
</input>
```

the DOM is like this:
[image: DOM]
and looks like this: [image: rendered result]

I found these relevant rules in the documentation which I believe I am following:

- Bindings can only occur in attribute-value and text-content positions.
- Templates should not contain unclosed elements—they will be closed by the HTML parser.
  Reference: [https://lit-html.polymer-project.org](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#template-structure)

I'm not successful in doing it that way. Anybody know of the way?
I can of course just separate them, but I would like a neat way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the documentation says:

> Bindings can only occur in attribute-value and text-content positions.

That is:

```
<element attribute="${/* Here */}">
  ${/* Or here */}
</element>
```

Try setting each attribute value according to the condition:

```
<paper-input placeholder=${condition ? this.videotitle : null}
             value=${condition ? null : this.videotitle}>
</paper-input>
```

Comment: Yes, this works as expected. Dunno why I didn't thought of doing it this way. Good work